# JSP Servlet Ajax Call (MVC) Iterate through JSON Objects

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, jsp, servlets

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
        $.get("/myServlet", function(responseJson) {                 
            var $container = $("#mySpace");
            var x = "";

            $.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {  
                var object = JSON.stringify(value);

                x+= " . "+object+"<br>";
             });
            $container.append(x);


        });
    });
```

//- ---------------------------------------------- Servlet ---------- ----

```
   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse 
 response) throws ServletException, IOException {

  ArrayList<Students> list = new ArrayList<>();

  Student s = new Student();
  s.setid(1);
  s.setName("john");
  s.setYear(5.5);

  Student s1 = new Student();
  s1.setid(2);
  s1.setName("alice");
  s1.setYear(5.5);

  Student s2 = new Student();
  s2.setid(3);
  s2.setName("nami");
  s2.setYear(3.5);

  list.add(s);
  list.add(s1);
  list.add(s2);

        String json = new Gson().toJson(list);
         response.setContentType("application/json");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().write(json);
```

}

My x in javascript produces this. Even when i try to access the object["id"] eg x+= " . "+object["id"]+"
"; im unable to. it says undefined. Any advice on this? Or should i Use the Student Model i created in this? (not sure how though)

output of container:

. {"id":1,"name":"john","year":5.5}

. {"id":2,"name":"alice","year":5.5}

. {"id":3,"name":"nami","year":3.5}

Comment: Try this snippet might help you.     `$.each(responseJson, function(key,value) {     
 var object = JSON.parse(value);
     x+= " . "+object.id+"<br>";
});`

Comment: @Veeresh hi, thank you for reply. Nothing is being displayed. Guess there is errors - Unexpected token o in JSON.

Comment: Okay . I have updated my answer. Can you try that?

Comment: it's  because of `stringify`, you need to parse the json not turn it into a string..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will work.

```
$(document).ready(function() {          
        $.get("/myServlet", function(responseJson) {
        var $container = $("#mySpace");
        var x = "";
        var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseJson);
                $.each(jsonData, function(key,value) { 
                    x+= " . "+value.id+" "+value.name+" "+value.year+"<br>";
                 });
                 console.log(x);
                 $container.append(x);
          });
    });
```

Comment: Apparently theres an error on  var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseJson);